# does in php calling one function from another increase execution time?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, php-7

I have form data. I have to check if every variable should not have particular data so i have created another function to check. But i have to call that function many time as i have lots of variables to check. does calling a function from another function increase execution time ?

here i am calling function `checkVariable()` from this function

```
public function saveUser() {
    $name = $this->checkVariable(Input::get('name'));
    $last_name = $this->checkVariable(Input::get('lastname'));
    $age = $this->checkVariable(Input::get('age'));
    $salary = $this->checkVariable(Input::get('salary')); 
    return;
}
```

`checkVariable()` function to check variable

```
function checkVariable($data) {
    return $data == 'xyz' ? NULL : $data;
}
```

it is working properly. but i have doubt about execution time that it will increase execution time.
you can suggest any other way to do the same ?

Comment: Creating functions for a repetitive tasks is what you should do, so your code is up to par. Unless you've noticed any issues, don't worry about the performance in cases like this. Premature micro-optimization is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see any difference in execution time, neither in memory usage in your case. I think its ok to have such method, because you can reuse it where you need it. Use SOLID principles in most cases and you will be ok.
If you would use method recursion many many times, then memory consumption would be much higher than doing something in loop, but it has to be really a lot of recursion calls or very heavy methods.